# Where can i get support for JDK 1.6.0_25 and NetBeans 6.8

Tags: java, java-6, netbeans6.8

My organization has old code that we are trying to modify. 
It was developed on JDK 1.6.0_25.

I attempted to install this JDK and a version of NetBeans that supports it (6.8) but the installation was unsuccessful.

I get an error stating the the version is unsupported.

Does anyone know where i can receive support for these old versions of Oracle product?

Comment: .... it is very possible to install both those versions. you may want to be more precise, which version/product is not supported, what is the exact error message?

Comment: Do you know if the error is coming from installation of the IDE or from installation of the JDK?  (You can also use newer versions of the JDK to compile against older bytecode, by the way.)

Comment: On what machine? Have you made sure the architecture is correct?

Comment: It's not clear whether you're using netbeans as a development platform? Otherwise I'd say that IDE's generally allow you to specify which jdk you want to use in java projects? So use the existing Netbeans that you have and switch jdks to the 1.6 one in your project

Comment: The error is when trying to install the old NetBeans. Yes, the architecture is correct. I will try installing the latest NetBeans and pointing it to the JDK1.6 Update 25